# Missing CompileAs option on vcxproj generated by cmake 3.18.1

Tags: cmake, vcxproj

When I generate the .vcxproj for my project with cmake 3.2.1, it generates the line `<CompileAs>CompileAsCpp</CompileAs>`
But when I try the cmake version 3.18.1, the generated .vcxproj file does not contain that previous line causing my tests to fail (the code compiles).
Here the cmake code which set the project properties :

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRC})

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL MATCHES "(msdev|devenv|nmake|MSBuild)")
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "/TP")
endif()

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PUBLIC_INCLUDES} ${PRIVATE_INCLUDES} )
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

How can I ask to cmake to generate that missing line (`<CompileAs>CompileAsCpp</CompileAs>`)?
Thank you.

Comment: How does that missing tag result in your tests failing? What kind of files are in PROJECT_SRC? Also, what version of visual studio are you genearting code for?

Comment: Reading the code for a bit, it seems weird that you need this /TP flag. You should be able to set the project language to CXX and CMake does the rest.

Comment: Hi @Botje, Thank you for your answer. I am generating a VS2015 solution but I work with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: My code is in C but the dll should be compiled as C++ in order to be used in the test project. I tried to define my main project as CXX but I didn't work. I also tried to set the CXX standard to 11 but still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use CMake 3.18.0 and it worked.
The CompileAs tag was generated so I will use this version instead of the CMake 3.18.1

Thank you.